# Windows 7 and three monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a Dell Dimension E520 PC (4 years old now) and for a long time I've had a dual monitor set up using a Sapphire Radeon HD3600 series dual-DVI video card.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.

Recently I purchased a PCI (not PCI-E) graphics card, which happens to be an ATI 7000 Series card (quite old).  I slotted into my PC and booted up, after which Windows 7 showed it in device manager as Standard VGA Adapter, but on the display properties I couldn't see any monitors attached to it.

I went into the BIOS and chose the PCI card as the on-boot video card, and Windows proceeded to boot ON THAT CARD ONLY.  When I look at display properties it now only lists the single PCI video card, but in device manager it lists both cards.

Now I've booted back with the PCI-E card selected in the BIOS, and same problem, except this time the Standard VGA Graphics Adapter is appearing in Device Manager with an error - "This device cannot start (Code 10)".

Any ideas what on earth is going on?  My end goal is a three monitor set up.

Answer (score 1):

Do these cards use the same driver package?  Are you using the newest one?  If not, you should be.  Windows 7 is generally good about letting different cards coexist with newer drivers, but these may be too different.

It's also possible that this motherboard simply doesn't know how to map that much address space - this is often the cause of Code 10 errors.  You might try removing some of the RAM from the machine and seeing if it works (while you may not want to RUN it that way, especially if it doesn't have that much to begin with, it's a good test because if it starts working you've at least found your culprit.)